# How do I get my pie chart to show category names instead of series?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

So I have pie charts that are reading from data that changes dynamically when I run a program. In my pie chart, I display percentage [20%...30%...] in my Legend Entries (Series) section of the 'Select Data Source' and category name [red,blue,green,yellow] in my horizontal (Category) Axis labels. The category name is not set in stone, meaning a purple can be added into the list if I reran and generated my data. The percentages are calculated with a denominator using the total of all the possible colors.

However even after I formatted my pie charts to have the labels I prefer and saved it, when I rerun my data the category labels get replaced with [1,2,3,4,5] instead of [red,blue,green,yellow]. When I look at the data labels options bar, category is highlighted which means that excel is not picking up my category names but is just labeling them as '1,2,3,4,5'. Is there any way to fix this?

Edit: Adding pictures. So I noticed that when there is no data in the range that the pie chart is supposed to pick up (before I generate the data, shown in picture #1), the series is in 1,2,3,4,5. But even after I populate the data, the category values are not being read. Excel can't seem to auto-detect the categories and add them into the pie chart, as seen in picture #2.

[image: Blank chart, no data that is being picked up]

[image: populated chart but with no categories]

Comment: If I 'select data', copy the data range, delete it, reinsert it, and hit ok, the horizontal axis labels show up properly. However when I first generate it, it is still being labeled as 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Please add some screenshots to help us understanding your issue

Comment: I tried to add pictures, but were only limited to 2. If you need more I can provide them hopefully